# Can or should the limits be one-sided in defintion of directional derivative and proof that it is equal to the differential of the mapping?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, definition, differential-topology

**In the following, will changing any, or all of the standard limits
( $\xi\to0$ ) to one-sided limits ($\xi\to0^{+}$) change the meaning
of the expressions?** Notice in particular, in the proof of Theorem 2.1
$\xi\left|\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right|$ is not equivalent to $\left|\xi\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right|.$

The definitions and theorem are based on C.H. Edwards's Advanced Calculus
of Several Variables, section II-2.

The *first difference at* $\mathfrak{x}$ of the mapping $\vec{f}:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{m}$
is defined as
$$
\Delta\vec{f}_{\mathfrak{x}}\left(\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right)=\vec{f}\left(\mathfrak{x}+\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right)-\vec{f}\left(\mathfrak{x}\right).
$$

Assuming the limit exists, the *directional derivative with respect
to* $\Delta\mathfrak{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ of $\vec{f}:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{m}$
at $\mathfrak{x}$ is defined to be

\begin{align*}
D_{\Delta\mathfrak{x}} & \vec{f}\left(\mathfrak{x}\right)=\lim_{\xi\to0}\frac{\Delta\vec{f}_{\mathfrak{x}}\left(\xi\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right)}{\xi}.
\end{align*}

The mapping $\vec{f}:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{m}$ is said to
be *differentiable at* $\mathfrak{x}$ if and only if there exists a
linear mapping $d\vec{f}_{\mathfrak{x}}:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{m},$
called the *differential of* $\vec{f}$ *at* $\mathfrak{x},$ such that

$$
\mathfrak{0}=\lim_{\Delta\mathfrak{x}\to\mathfrak{0}}\frac{\Delta\vec{f}_{\mathfrak{x}}\left(\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right)-d\vec{f}_{\mathfrak{x}}\left(\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right)}{\left|\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right|}.
$$

Theorem 2.1 If $\vec{f}:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{m}$ is differentiable
at $\mathfrak{x},$ then the directional derivative exists for all
$\Delta\mathfrak{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n},$ and

$$
D_{\Delta\mathfrak{x}}\vec{f}\left(\mathfrak{x}\right)=d\vec{f}_{\mathfrak{x}}\left(\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right).
$$

Proof: In the equation defining differentiability, substitute $\Delta\mathfrak{x}\mapsto\xi\Delta\mathfrak{x},$
so that

\begin{align*}
\mathfrak{0}= & \lim_{\xi\to0}\frac{\Delta\vec{f}_{\mathfrak{x}}\left(\xi\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right)-d\vec{f}_{\mathfrak{x}}\left(\xi\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right)}{\left|\xi\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right|}\\
= & \frac{1}{\left|\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right|}\left(\lim_{\xi\to0}\frac{\Delta\vec{f}_{\mathfrak{x}}\left(\xi\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right)-d\vec{f}_{\mathfrak{x}}\left(\xi\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right)}{\xi}\right)\\
= & D_{\Delta\mathfrak{x}}\vec{f}\left(\mathfrak{x}\right)-d\vec{f}_{\mathfrak{x}}\left(\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right).
\end{align*}

Comment: Why not define the derivatives at a point $x$ rather than at that weird squiggle thing? You can use $x$ and $y$ and then for a fixed direction you can use $d$ or $v$ and for a scalar to go to zero you can use $h\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Are you talking about the Greek letter $\xi$? https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_01.html  or perhaps Fraktur font Latin x, $\mathfrak{x}$? https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2018/07/21/fraktur-math/  The reason I used the definition given, is because that's how Edwards does it.

Comment: The book Convex Analysis by Rockafellar on page 213 defines the one sided directional derivative of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow [-\infty, \infty]$ at a point $x$ where $f$ is finite, and with respect to a vector $v$, by $$D_vf(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(x+hv) - f(x)}{h}$$ whenever the limit exists. Actually it uses $f'(x;v)=D_vf(x)$ but I modified to match your notation. It says the directional derivative is "two sided" if $D_{-v}f(x)$ exists and $D_{-v}f(x)=-D_vf(x)$. It says that if $f$ is differentiable at $x$ the directional derivatives are all finite and two-sided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, making the limit in the definition of the directional derivative one-sided changes the meaning of the definition.  It may be instructive or useful to examine such one-sided limits, but the standard limit provides the common definition of the directional derivative.

Regarding the limit appearing in the proof of Theorem 2.1, the following seems to justify using a standard (two-sided) limit.

- Rewrite the definition of differentiability using $\left|\xi\right|$.
- This is equivalent to writing the limit from the right without the absolute value on $\xi$.
- Since the definition applies to all $\Delta\mathfrak{x},$ the equation holds if we replace $\Delta\mathfrak{x}\mapsto{-\Delta\mathfrak{x}}.$
- Since $\mathfrak{0}=-\mathfrak{0},$ the equation holds when we multiply the denominator by $-1.$
- This produces the limit from the left of the same expression for which we originally wrote the limit from the right.
- Thus we have a two-sided limit.

\begin{align*}
\mathfrak{0}= & \lim_{\Delta\mathfrak{x}\to\mathfrak{0}}\frac{\Delta\vec{f}_{\mathfrak{x}}\left(\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right)-d\vec{f}_{\mathfrak{x}}\left(\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right)}{\left|\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right|}\\
= & \frac{1}{\left|\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right|}\left(\lim_{\xi\to0}\frac{\Delta\vec{f}_{\mathfrak{x}}\left(\left|\xi\right|\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right)-d\vec{f}_{\mathfrak{x}}\left(\left|\xi\right|\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right)}{\left|\xi\right|}\right)\\
= & \frac{1}{\left|\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right|}\left(\lim_{\xi\to0^{+}}\frac{\Delta\vec{f}_{\mathfrak{x}}\left(\xi\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right)-d\vec{f}_{\mathfrak{x}}\left(\xi\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right)}{\xi}\right)\\
= & \frac{1}{\left|-\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right|}\left(\lim_{\xi\to0^{+}}\frac{\Delta\vec{f}_{\mathfrak{x}}\left(-\xi\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right)-d\vec{f}_{\mathfrak{x}}\left(-\xi\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right)}{\xi}\right)\\
= & -\frac{1}{\left|-\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right|}\left(\lim_{\xi\to0^{+}}\frac{\Delta\vec{f}_{\mathfrak{x}}\left(-\xi\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right)-d\vec{f}_{\mathfrak{x}}\left(-\xi\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right)}{-\xi}\right)\\
= & -\frac{1}{\left|-\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right|}\left(\lim_{\xi\to0^{-}}\frac{\Delta\vec{f}_{\mathfrak{x}}\left(\xi\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right)-d\vec{f}_{\mathfrak{x}}\left(\xi\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right)}{\xi}\right).
\end{align*}

The removal, in the proof, of the absolute value symbol on $\xi,$ and using the standard limit appear necessary in order to produce the formula for the directional derivative.

Note that the converse is not true.  The existence of the directional derivative for all $\Delta\mathfrak{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is necessary, but not sufficient to show that $\vec{f}$ is differentiable at $\mathfrak{x}$.